# Baseline alignment on BOTH pages

Tags: thesis, baseline

A friend of mine said to me that my (almost) finished Ph.D thesis would look much better if my baselines were always aligned (between left and right pages). How can i do that ? The picture is a screenshot of what I have now... At this point I think that is the fact of adding an image to my document that produce this misalignment... maybe ?

Here is a MWE, with a screenshot of the result :

[image: Screenshot fo my problem...]

```
% =================================================== Classe du document
\documentclass[11pt,
            twoside,
            a4paper,
            openright,
            %draft          %permet de voir les overfullbox
            ]{book}
% =================================================== géométrie des pages

\usepackage[a4paper,
            width=150mm,
            top=25mm,
            bottom=25mm,
            bindingoffset=0.1cm,
            headheight=65pt,
            %showframe      % afficher les limites du bloc de texte
            ]{geometry}

% =================================================== Packages divers   

\usepackage{lipsum}             %permet de générer du texte de remplissage
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}        % permet d'insérer des fichiers .pdf
\usepackage{microtype}          % réglage fin de la typographie 
\usepackage{graphicx}           % gère l'insertion de figures
\usepackage{booktabs}           % style des tableaux
\usepackage{multirow}           % tableaux avec cellules fusionnées
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}              %tableaux typographiquement corrects
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  % empeche les flottants de changer de section
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto, hidelinks]{hyperref}          % liens TOC et figures/tables cliquables
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{indentfirst}            %mettre une tabulation au début de tout les paragraphes
\usepackage{amsmath}                %caractères spéciaux dans les formules math (entre autre)
\usepackage{setspace}           %régler l'interlignage
\usepackage{layout}             %permet de lancer la commande \layout qui fait voir la mise en page du doc
\usepackage{placeins}           %permet d'utiliser \FloatBarrier pr forcer float rester ds section
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % pouvoir enlever les chiffres elzevirien des enviro. table
\usepackage{rotating}           %permet la rotation des figures avec leur légende
\usepackage{cleveref}                   % insère fig. ou table
\usepackage[french]{babel}      %polyglossia faisait buger la TOC (pas de n°aux parties)
\usepackage{fontspec}       % sert à sélectionner les polices facilement
\onehalfspacing                                             %régler l'interlignage 0.5

% =================================================== Début du document

\begin{document}


\frontmatter\
\lipsum

\mainmatter
\part{Test}
\lipsum
\cref{test}



\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{test.jpg}
\caption[test]{test}
\label{test}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\appendix
\lipsum

\backmatter
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers :)

Comment: Grid typesetting is rather difficult with latex. There are too many places where spaces are inserted that disrupt the grid.

Comment: definitely a consequence of adding the float/figure.  also possibly affected by an implicit `\flushbottom`.  as @UlrikeFischer says, grid typesetting isn't trivial.

Comment: AFAIK `ConTeXt` allows grid typesetting. You can also see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1430/100689

Comment: You can fix some of them with appropriate additions of \vfill to push the text to the top or bottom.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353085/text-in-two-columns-on-the-same-level