# How to (re)define margins for sectioning commands?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, grid-typesetting, scrreprt

I'm currently trying to adjust my document to the baseline grid and for that I want to change all margins of `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` (and floats) etc. to multiples of the `\baselineskip`. I found that `\titlespacing` can do that, but it seems to generate errors.

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0em}{2\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test} % Missing number, treated as zero. \section{Test}
                   % Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \section{Test}
    Test
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure what's happening here. I'm also getting `Non standard sectioning command \section(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.` warnings for all commands which suggests the packet might be incompatible with my class.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The KOMA class `scrreprt` has its own mechanisms to redefine the section commands, so using `titlesec` with it isn't quite advisable. BTW I get no error with this code, just the warnings.

Comment: Yea sorry, I found my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398652/adding-space-around-section-title-for-in-register-in-koma-script-context/484928

Comment: @sollniss So this question is a duplicate of the linked one and can be closed?

Comment: @esdd Yes [comment too short]